Determination of recycled content in plastics
I have heard that crystallinity percentage, as measured by X-ray diffraction, and the crystallization temperature, by differential scanning calorimetry, can be used to estimate the recycled content in plastic specimens. However, I can not find specific reports on this matter.
Which analytical techniques can be used to measure the recycled content in plastics?

There probably is no definitive method. Recycled polymers usually have lower MW but that can be countered by blending. We used gel permeation to measure MW distribution and careful comparison of Infrared, spectra and Thermal analysis, GSC and TGA. Occasionally analysis of ash composition and end group analysis gave clues.
